# subset counting using dynamic programing in java

Tags: java, subset

I am trying to write a java code for getting the total number of combinations of subset for which sum is equal to x where n is the number of elements using recursion ..I wrote the code but it seems it needs to be more optimized since its taking a lot of time to get the result

```
import java.util.*;
 class subset 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        int n,x,z;
        int m[]=new int[30];

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=sc.nextInt();
        x=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            m[i]=sc.nextInt();

        }
        z=func(0,m,x);
        System.out.println(z);
     }
     static int func(int i,int m[],int w)
     {
         if(i==m.length)
         {
             return 0;

         }
         if(m[i]==w)
             return (1+func(i+1,m,w));
         else
         {
             return((func(i+1,m,w-m[i])+func(i+1,m,w)));     

         }
```

Comment: Define "lots of time", and the inputs that make it take it. Trace out the algorithm using paper and pencil and see how many times you're recursing for small inputs.

Comment: well for input like n=3 and x=4 where the numbers are 1 2 3 the function System.currentTimeMillis() returns value 1408884631647

Comment: ... The current time in millis is precisely that--the current time in millis, e.g., `1408884631647` is `Sun Aug 24 2014 08:50:31 GMT-0400 (EDT)`. That's not a time *differential*, it's a *time*.

Comment: (E.g., if you want to *time* something, you need to subtract the start time from the end time, then do math to figure out the number of seconds. How long is it actually taking? You must have realized it wasn't taking ~45 years to complete.)

Comment: thanks for the info ..so this time i used the function   System.currentTimeMillis() to calculate the time difference and got the result 14251 i.e 14 sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I found out how to optimize it.I simply sorted out the inputs and the put a constraint the if the sum calculated by the func function becomes greater than the subset sum(i.e x) it will discard it.

```
import java.util.*;
class subset 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    int n,x,z;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=sc.nextInt();
    x=sc.nextInt();
    int m[]=new int[n];
    long b=System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        m[i]=sc.nextInt();

    }
    Arrays.sort(m);
    for(int i=0;i<m.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" "+m[i]+" " );

    }
    z=func(0,m,x);
    System.out.println(z);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-b);
 }
 static int func(int i,int m[],int w)
 {
     if(i==m.length||m[i]>w)
     {
         return 0;

     }
     if(m[i]==w)
         return (1+func(i+1,m,w));
     else
     {
         return((func(i+1,m,w-m[i])+func(i+1,m,w)));     

     }
 }
```

}